# Iterating an array of char using Java 8 Stream forEach method

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

facing one strange problem 
i am trying to iterate Array of char using stream foreach method , it is giving compile time error.if i am trying same with Array of integer it is working fine . any clue ?
code

```
String input = "test";
char[] chars = input.toCharArray();    
Arrays.stream(chars).forEach((e) -> {
   System.out.println(e); 
});
```

giving compiler error 
**The method stream(T[]) in the type Arrays is not applicable for the arguments (char[])**

if i change it to Array of int , it works fine

what i am missing ?

Answer (score 1):

There's no `CharStream`, which is why there's no `Arrays.stream()` method that accepts a `char[]`. The next closest thing is an `IntStream`.

You can use:

```
input.chars().forEach(e -> System.out.println((char) e));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use forEach you should use its loop version:

```
    String input = "test";
    char[] chars = input.toCharArray();    
    for (char c : chars) {
        System.out.println(c);
    }
```

If you definitely need Stream API forEach you can wrap array in list:

```
    String input = "test";
    char[] chars = input.toCharArray();    
    Arrays.asList(chars).stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Easier: Stream.of(chars).forEach(System.out::println)

Answer (score 0):

The actual error you see is:

```
|  no suitable method found for stream(char[])
|      method java.util.Arrays.<T>stream(T[]) is not applicable
|        (inference variable T has incompatible bounds
|          equality constraints: char
|          lower bounds: java.lang.Object)
|      method java.util.Arrays.<T>stream(T[],int,int) is not applicable
|        (cannot infer type-variable(s) T
|          (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
|      method java.util.Arrays.stream(int[]) is not applicable
|        (argument mismatch; char[] cannot be converted to int[])
|      method java.util.Arrays.stream(long[]) is not applicable
|        (argument mismatch; char[] cannot be converted to long[])
|      method java.util.Arrays.stream(double[]) is not applicable
```

so if you look in the [documentation of the `java.util.Arrays` class](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html) and look for the `stream` method you will indeed see only that the `stream` method is overloaded for

- `double[]` returning a `DoubleStream`
- `int[]`  returning an `IntStream`
- `long[]`  returning a `LongStream`
- `T[]`  returning a `Stream<T>`

There just isn't a `CharStream`.

You're best bet, IMHO is to do:

```
jshell> String input = "test";
input ==> "test"

jshell> input.codePoints().forEach((c) -> { System.out.println(c); })
116
101
115
116
```

or

```
jshell> input.codePoints().forEach((c) -> { System.out.println((char)c); })
t
e
s
t
```

The other answers to this question have other alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

The reason which I know Stream is accepting Character, not char.

Where
char is a primitive type that represents a single 16 bit Unicode character while Character is a wrapper class that allows us to use char primitive concept in OOP-kind of way.

```
    char[] chars = input.toCharArray();
    Character[] charObjectArray = ArrayUtils.toObject(chars);
    Arrays.stream(charObjectArray).forEach((e) -> {
       System.out.println(e); 
    });
```

If you upcast char to Character, then it will allow iteration.